What is the first relative homology group of the torus relative to k points?
I came up with this question and i am puzzled by what i have done so far.
Let $X = T$ be the torus and $A$ a set of $k$ points in $T$. I want to compute $H_n (X,A)$. This is what i have done so far:
we have the long exact sequence: $$...  \rightarrow H_n(A) \xrightarrow{i_\star} H_n(X) \xrightarrow{j_\star} H_n(X,A) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(A) \rightarrow...\rightarrow H_0(X,A) \xrightarrow{\partial} 0$$
where ${i_\star}$ is the map induced by inclusion, ${j_\star}$ is induced by the quotient and $\partial$ is the boundary map (as defined in Hatcher). We know that $H_2(X) \cong H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb {Z^2}$ and is trivial for higher $n$, while $H_0(A) \cong \mathbb Z^k$ and is trivial for other  $n$.
Lets find $H_0(X,A)$: we have $$\mathbb {Z}^k \xrightarrow{i_\star} \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{j_\star} H_0(X,A) \xrightarrow{\partial} 0$$
the map $i_\star$ sends each (class of) point into the generator of $H_0(X)$, so $i_\star$ is surjective. Exactness implies that $j_\star$ is trivial, so that $H_0(X,A) \cong \mathbb Z$.
Lets now find $H_1(X,A)$ (the problem i am having): we have $$0  \xrightarrow{i_\star} \mathbb Z^2 \xrightarrow{j_\star} H_1(X,A) \xrightarrow{\partial} \mathbb Z^k \xrightarrow{i_\star} \mathbb Z$$ By the first isomorphism theorem we have $$H_1(X,A) / Ker \ \partial \cong Im \ \partial = Ker \ i_\star \cong \mathbb Z^{k-1}$$ we also have $Ker \ \partial = Im \ j_\star \cong  \mathbb Z^2$. This gives us $H_1(X,A) \cong \mathbb Z^{k+1}$. If we now set $k = 0$ we have $H_1(X) = H_1(X,A) \cong \mathbb Z$ wich is not true. Where am i wrong?

$H_0(X, A)$ is not $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\Z$ (unless $k = 0$): It is trivial. In fact, you observe correctly that in the sequence
$$
    \Z^k \xrightarrow{i_*} \Z \xrightarrow{j_*} H_0(X, A) \to 0
$$
the map $i_*$ is surjective and therefore that $j_*$ is trivial, and this implies that $H_0(X, A) = 0$ (why you think this implies $H_0(X, A) \cong \Z$ instead I have no idea).
(Side note: You should convince yourself using this type of argument that $H_0(Y, B)$ is free with basis given by the classes of points of $Y$ which lie in path-components of $Y$ not met by $B$, one per component.)
Again assuming $k > 0$, plugging this into the long exact sequence of the pair, you get a short exact sequence
$$
    0 \to \underbrace{H_1(X)}_{\cong \Z^2} \to H_1(X, A) \to \underbrace{\Z^{k - 1}}_{\cong \ker i_*} \to 0
$$
and arrive at
$$
    H_i(X, A) \cong \begin{cases}
        0 & i = 0 \text{ or } i \geq 3 \\
        \Z^{k + 1} & i = 1 \\
        \Z & i = 2
    \end{cases}
$$
The case $k = 0$ you have to treat separately: In this case $H_i(A) = 0$ in all degrees (including 0!), so $H_*(X, A) \cong H_*(X)$ as you'd hopefully expect. In particular, in degree $i = 1$ that seems to be troubling you, the relevant part of the exact sequence is
$$
    0 \xrightarrow{i_*} \Z^2 \xrightarrow{j_*} H_1(X, A) \xrightarrow{\partial} \underbrace{0}_{= H_0(A)} \xrightarrow{i_*} \Z \xrightarrow{j_*} \Z \to 0
$$
I'll leave it to you to compare this to your calculation and spot the mistake :)

Thank you for the detailed answer! I didnt see i had to consider the case k = 0 separately and i just assumed everything else was wrong. I actually did calculate $H_0(X,A)$ to be trivial on my notes but for some reason i wrote the integers in my post....

The problem is that the formula $\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ doesn't make sense when $k=0$. What happens in this case Ker $i=0$ (it has to be since its domain is trivial). From this you get $H_1(X,A)/Ker \partial\cong 0$, and so $H_1(X,A)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, as expected.
